# Flair images return 500 errors on flair page

Tags: bug, flair

I'm not sure if other pages are effected but I'm getting a 500 error on all images with the following url types from the [flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311366/x-o/flair), if I remove the theme query string it loads fine. I've tried this on multiple computers and both on 4G/3G and WiFi.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2311366.png?theme=hotdog

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 11:40:31 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 06:46:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 06:46:36 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: 8c2c4d74-1e2c-4111-b390-81ad7fda05f6
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 2143aa8b590819b6-SYD
```

Comment: Works for me. The image loads both with and without the theme.

Comment: Well obviously there's something going on, I'm not sure if you downvoted this or someone else but if there's an issue it needs to be seen to. 

Also I'm only getting the error on the themed versions so that kind of proves it's a issue with the backend and not my internet, etc.

Comment: Nobody has voted so far on your question. Can you capture the raw response (HTTP headers, HTTP body) and include it in your question? You can use Fiddler or your browser's dev tools for that.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` when making the request. It seems it is hosted at CloudFare which is where the problem is? Hard to tell exactly.

Comment: This may have something to do with them migrating servers recently.

Comment: Looks fine now; blip?

Comment: If it is a problem with them switching servers that'd explain it as the Sydney Cloudflare server is known to have issues from time to time, no clue why it does though. I've added the HTTP response to the post.

Comment: It works fine for me as well.

Comment: Not working for me either: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/4691784.png?theme=default

No theme loads except for the default. And the default loads without my image!

Comment: This has just started happening for me (some 6+ years later!?). I've not touched my profile page for a while and it was working fine until recently and there were two instances of multi-hour server work over the weekend...?