# My Flair and those of others return an HTTP 500 instead of the expected image

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flair

I have the same problem as reported in [Flair images return 500 errors on flair page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302234/flair-images-return-500-errors-on-flair-page) but I'm pretty sure Flair worked somewhere between 2015 and today so this is a regression.

When visiting my [Stack Overflow Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/578411.png)  or that of [Kathryn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/7948068.png) I get served a 500 error. My [network flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/281857.png) as well as the [meta flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380133/my-flair-and-those-of-others-return-an-http-500-instead-of-the-expected-image#comment669855_380133) is unaffected.

Even when logged out the flair doesn't work for me, so it is not related to me being in a Team this time ;)

Here are the headers I get in case this is a Fastly error local to the Netherlands:

```
Request URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/578411.png
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 151.101.193.69:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=86400
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 22:17:31 GMT
expires: Wed, 13 Feb 2019 22:17:31 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 22:17:31 GMT
status: 500
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
vary: Fastly-SSL
via: 1.1 varnish
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: c1858403-6bd6-49f6-8dc8-f270cf1db29b
x-served-by: cache-ams21024-AMS
x-timer: S1550009851.354476,VS0,VE83
```

I repro-ed on Chrome ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCkor.png)), Edge and Firefox. Strangely enough at least one user reported that they can see the flair fine, so I might be unlucky and have been assigned the only broken server in the webfarm.

Can this be looked at?

Comment: I can see the flairs of both users fine as well.

Comment: I cannot see either SO flair, but the network flair is fine.

Comment: How about the Meta flair? Both your examples work for me with the meta flair: [yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/578411.png) / [Kathryn's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/7948068.png).

Comment: Both of there flairs work perfectly for me.

Comment: [elections page looks funny now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKV7K.png). Also it works on mobile internet for me.

Comment: No repro. rene's links look fine for me, as does the elections page, both at home and from work. I'd say it's a Netherlands thing, but apparently it's broken for @Bhargav, too?

Comment: Yep. @Cody. Broken for me on my residential wifi network, but works on my mobile LTE network. So it is a worldwide issue.

Comment: No repro here, from another Dutchie. I am not in any team, if that matters.

Comment: Another non-repro, on wifi from Europe, and I am part of a team.

Comment: Same here: No repro, Dutch, on a team :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Copied from my [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323891/broken-images-on-election-page/323895#323895):

> We had a web server that was misbehaving in ways that really don't
>   make any sense, and as part of a debug of things, a reboot magically
>   fixed it. System.Drawing (being swapped soon) was saving 0 byte files
>   *only on this box* (`ny-web05`). This meant all users had a 1 in 9 chance of hitting the issue, for all flair from the box. Unfortunately
>   `System.Drawing` throws an `OutOfMemory` exception for *everything*
>   and is damn near useless in terms of debugging anything
>   after-the-fact.
>
> Since we're going to replace all this code for the .NET Core port
>   here, I'm not advising we spend any more time digging into it...it's
>   just not a good use of resources.
>
> TL;DR: I know *what* it was doing, but not *why* it was doing it. And
>   the symptoms are no longer there to debug. So we'll call this a fluke.

Comment: Still broken for me, should I blame caching?

Comment: @BhargavRao which URL are you hitting? Can you verify it's still happening on a hard reload now?

Comment: The /election one. A hard reload fixed it. Thanks.